# Routing issue or parameter issue?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I created 3 methods to test attribute routing.
My 2 GET methods appear to be running, however I can't understand how to get my post method to work.

Is my route wrong on the post method or am I incorrectly passing the wrong data to the method?

My controller:

```
 [RoutePrefix("api/myTest")]
    public class JobController : ApiController
    {
        [Route("{id:int}")]
        [HttpGet]
        public string GetJob(int id)
        {
            return String.Format("Job-{0}", id.ToString());
        }

        [Route("GetJob2/{id:int}")]
        [HttpGet]
        public string GetJob2(int id)
        {
            return String.Format("New and improved Job-{0}", id.ToString());
        }

        [Route("NewJob/{data}")]
        [HttpPost]
        public HttpResponseMessage NewJob(HttpRequestMessage request)
        {
           // Read and process xml
        }
    }
```

In my JS I have:

```
$.get('api/myTest/' + $("#jobID").val())  // Works
$.get('api/myTest/GetJob2/' + $("#jobID").val()) // Works
var data = "<root><name>Bob</name></root>";
$.post('api/myTest/NewJob/', data)  // Fails 404 Error
```

UPDATE:

```
    [Route("NewJob/{data}")]
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage NewJob(string request)
```

UPDATE 2:

```
[Route("NewJob/{data}")]
        [HttpPost]
        public HttpResponseMessage NewJob(string data)  
        {

        }

var data = "<root><name>Bob</name></root>";
        $.post('api/myTest/NewJob/', data)
        .done(function (result) { alert("done"); })
        .fail(function (xhr, status, err) {
            alert(xhr.responseText);
        });
```

Comment: The param of `NewJob` should be of `string` type.

Comment: what is the error ? there have any additional information following the  "Fails 404 Error"

Comment: I'm just seeing 404 - Not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Straight from webapi [Attribute Routing documentation](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#constraints) and there is table of supported constraints too in the same link.

**Route Constraints**

> Route constraints let you restrict how the parameters in the route template are matched. The general syntax is "{parameter:constraint}". For example:

```
[Route("users/{id:int}"]
public User GetUserById(int id) { ... }

[Route("users/{name}"]
public User GetUserByName(string name) { ... }
```

> Here, the first route will only be selected if the "id" segment of the URI is an integer. Otherwise, the second route will be chosen.

In case of XML, you are not passing any data through url, so this is how your route is

```
[Route("NewJob")]
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage NewJob(HttpRequestMessage data)
{
               // Read and process xml
}
```

**And specify xml in jQuery POST**

```
var url = "";
var data = "";
$.ajax({
            contentType: "text/xml",
            dataType: "xml",
            type: "post",
            url: url,
            data: data
        });
```

Further, your previous call was

```
$.post('api/myTest/NewJob/', data) it should be '+' instead of ','
$.post('api/myTest/NewJob/'+ data)
```

lower one would give url invalid that is 400 instead of 404

Comment: Thanks!  It's now making that call.

Answer (score 0):

What happens is that your client is sending a request that should match an action with `NewJob` name, but the param type that your action is expecting is of type `HttpRequestMessage`, and the param in the request is of `string` type.

So change the action to this:

```
    [Route("NewJob/{data}")]
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage NewJob(string data)
    {
       // Read and process xml
    }
```

It should works now.

Comment: Isn't that the same thing I have above?

Comment: Ohh I haven't realized that the name in the route didn't match the name in the param. I already changed it.

Comment: I'm still getting the 404.